# Angular 6: Make directive visible to parent from ng-content using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create custom Angular Material components in Angular 6.
I tried to setup something like this :

custom-input.component.html

```
<custom-input-wrapper>
        <input matInput/>
</custom-input-wrapper>
```

custom-input-wrapper.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="field-wrapper" #field>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

Obviously, an error is triggered as MatFormField has no visibility inside `<ng-content>` to reference any MatInput instance :

```
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl
```

Is there a way to make the content inside a `<ng-content>` accessible to it's parents ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-make-directive-visible-to-parent-from-ng-content-usin?file=src/app/custom-input-wrapper/custom-input-wrapper.component.ts

getting the MatFormFieldControl ContentChild and assigning it to the MatFormField _control property.

Comment: It does! Thank you!